# Automatic digitization

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, imagery, feature-extraction

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible to auto digitize a satellite image on ArcGIS 10.5. I need the building shapefile of a large remote area.

I tried manual digitizing but its been stressful. I'm using ArcGIS 10.5.

Below is the image I'm trying to digitize. I need to show the roads and buildings.

Answer (score 1):

You could reference [About automatic vectorization](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/about-batch-vectorization.htm)

> Automatic (batch) vectorization can involve a series of procedures to achieve an acceptable raster-to-vector conversion. It can be as simple as executing one command to generate the vector features. Depending on the state of the input raster data you are working with, the vectorization process varies. This section is intended to provide an overview of the automatic vectorization experience.

Also, [ArcScan](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/arcscan-tutorial-interactive-vectorization.htm)

> ArcScan makes it easy to create new features from scanned raster images. This process can significantly reduce the time it takes you to incorporate raster data into your vector database.

In this exercise, you will generate features from a scanned parcel map by interactively tracing raster cells. You will begin by starting ArcMap and loading a map document that contains the raster dataset and two layers.

Here is a tutorial you can use as well as an example in QGIS, as an alternative GIS application [Unit 5.5: Auto Digitizing](https://learn.canvas.net/courses/464/pages/unit-5-dot-5-auto-digitizing)

Comment: I thought arcsacn works only for black and white images